# How do photovoltaic panels obey the law of conservation of energy?

Tags: energy-conservation, conservation-laws, solar-cells

The sun shines on a photovoltaic panel and it makes electrical energy, presumably by absorbing the photons in the incident light.

But where does the energy transferred into electricity come from? Does solar electricity make the earth a little darker, or a little cooler, for example?

If it does one of those things, how much electrical energy would we need to generate to make an observable change in the environment?

Comment: The energy comes from those photons absorbed from the incident light. Plants do that also, in photosynthesis.

Comment: Re, "Does solar electricity make the earth a little darker." Absolutely! Yes! If you stand in the shadow of a solar array, the space around you will be significantly darker than if you were standing in full sunlight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the energy comes from the absorbed photons. A photon has a frequence-dependent energy

$$E=hf$$

where $h$ is [Planck's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) and $f$ is the frequency.

Being sunlight, these photons come from the sun. For more information, you might want to refer to [Light formed by the sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103987/) and [The source of the light we see from the Sun](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3563/).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, photons are converted to electricity by the panels. This does absorb a small amount of light that could have been absorbed, reflected, or refracted back into Earth's environment. But the electricity produced by the panels is not stored permanently. When it is used it is mainly converted to light or heat. So, long term, all of the energy converted by the panels returns to the environment. No energy is truly lost.

Comment: Ah! So, if I absorb the light, make it electricity, and dissipate it into say, sound via a speaker, the net effect is that the world is slightly darker? I wonder how much it would change...